# Missing Entries from Core Data Database

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I am the developer of an [open-source finance tracker](https://github.com/rarfell/dimeApp/) Dime that is built on Core Data. In my recent v2 update, I changed my Core Data infrastructure a little - using a static shared instance of DataController instead of just initializing it each time I needed to use it. This change was made so that I could add AppIntents functionality - without it, I would get an error about 2 data model's being loaded.

However, following this change, I have been getting 2-3 emails on a daily basis about newly added transactions disappearing after a few days, when they quit the app. This is not a widespread experience among all users - and I have been unable to recreate it on my own.

Any assistance on this will be immensely appreciated. Thank you so so much!

You can check out the full open-source project here: https://github.com/rarfell/dimeApp/

Here is the new CoreData infrastructure:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = DataController()

    var container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MainModel")

    init() {
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)

        let keyValueStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default

        if keyValueStore.object(forKey: "icloud_sync") == nil {
            keyValueStore.set(true, forKey: "icloud_sync")
        }

        if !keyValueStore.bool(forKey: "icloud_sync") {
            description.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
        } else {
            description.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "iCloud.com.rafaelsoh.dime")
        }

        let groupID = "group.com.rafaelsoh.dime"

        if let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: groupID) {
            description.url = url.appendingPathComponent("Main.sqlite")
        }

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in

            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo) for \(description)")
            }

            self.container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        }
    }
}
```

and I would use the model this way:

```
let dataController = DataController.shared
```

Here is the old Core Data infrastructure that never had missing transactions after addition:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    var container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MainModel")
    
    init() {
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        
        if(!NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.bool(forKey: "icloud_sync")){
            description.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
        } else {
            description.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "iCloud.com.rafaelsoh.dime")

        }
        
        
        let groupID = "group.com.rafaelsoh.dime"
        
        if let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: groupID) {
            description.url = url.appendingPathComponent("Main.sqlite")
        }
        
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions =  [description]
        
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo) for \(description)")
            }
            
            self.container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
            
        }
    }
}
```

and I would use the model this way:

```
struct dimeApp: App {
    @StateObject var dataController: DataController
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
                .environmentObject(dataController)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        let dataController = DataController()
        _dataController = StateObject(wrappedValue: dataController)
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this would be it. It sounds more like the context isn't being saved or CloudKit and the Local store are out of sync. It can easily happen if you changed the model and the user didn't update all devices.

Comment: hey @loremipsum, thanks for the reply! will look through my codebase and see if i am missing out on any moc.save()s. is there any way to address the cloudkit issue? my apologies, am a really novice ios developer.

Comment: Their used to be a really good article out there that talked about this but I cannot find it. The solution is to make sure the user updates all the devices and then “destroy” the local store. Everything will go in sync again. As a prevention the person that wrote the article recommended that you roll out any CoreData model changes long before you roll out the functionality that uses the changes so the user can update devices on their own time.